# Custom attribute not working in cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cart, custom-attributes

We have an "Yes/No" product attribute and we need this information on product image renderer.
So I have overrided the ImageFactory.php with di preference.

The code looks like that:

```
private function isAttribute(Product $product): bool
{
    if ($product->getAttributeText('attribute_value') == 'Yes') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The result is always false on cart page. This code works on all places like the product details page but not on the cart page! Why?

I have cleaned all caches of corse. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add code in your module in location below

Vendor/Module/etc/catalog_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
     <attribute name="customattributecode"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that is working!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Store -> Attributes -> Product

now select and open your attribute and set **"Used in Product Listing" --> "Yes"**

now you can get attribute value in cart

Comment: Thanks that is helpful but I have already done this.